# SVG : How to merge the paths of an SVG into a single path?

Tags: svg, inkscape

How to merge all svg image paths into a single path ?

I'm trying to get a single path with contours of the SVG image below.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1105.04 782.74">
  <g transform="translate(-47.24 -58.63)">
    <path fill="#ff0000"
      d="m 61.08,396.83 c 153.08053,-29.59584 98.70463,188.17778 101.49,254.17 -0.17,-0.05 -0.32,-0.11 -0.48,-0.17 -2.68,-1.06 -5.34,-2.18 -8,-3.38 l -1.7,-0.77 c -2.66667,-1.26 -5.33333,-2.59333 -8,-4 -0.93,-0.49 -1.86,-1 -2.78,-1.52 -14.80417,-8.29279 -28.25298,-18.80094 -39.88,-31.16 -0.34,-0.33 -0.66,-0.68 -1,-1 -1.62,-1.76 -3.21,-3.54 -4.75,-5.36 l -1.7,-2 c -1.82,-2.23 -3.58,-4.52 -5.29,-6.84 -0.25,-0.34 -0.49,-0.68 -0.75,-1 -6.954529,-9.64272 -12.728994,-20.08376 -17.2,-31.1 -0.14,-0.33 -0.26,-0.69 -0.39,-1 -1.373333,-3.53333 -2.59,-7.1 -3.65,-10.7 -0.46,-1.51 -0.9,-3 -1.28,-4.57 -0.14,-0.46 -0.26,-0.91 -0.37,-1.36 C 59.67,522.9 59,499.87 59,477 v -8 c 0,-9.25 0.11,-18.56 0.27,-27.86 0,-2.41 0.1,-4.81 0.15,-7.23 0.14,-6.14 0.34,-12.28 0.6,-18.42 0.06,-1.71 0.14,-3.41 0.23,-5.11 0,-0.98 0.05,-1.96 0.15,-2.94 0.24,-3.56 0.44,-7.09 0.68,-10.61 z" />
    <path fill="#008000"
      d="m 106.9,242.81 c 9.04946,-14.16423 18.93707,-27.77514 29.61,-40.76 8.27,-10.16 17,-20.06 26.06,-29.6 2.89351,66.44329 8.44745,70.36 -55.67,70.36 z" />
    <path fill="#0000ff"
      d="m 61.4,392.55 c 0,-0.42 0.07,-0.85 0.1,-1.27 0.09,-1.15 0.18,-2.3 0.28,-3.44 0.11,-1.34 0.23,-2.69 0.36,-4 0.13,-1.31 0.27,-2.91 0.42,-4.36 0.15,-1.45 0.29,-2.92 0.46,-4.37 0.17,-1.45 0.32,-2.9 0.5,-4.34 0.18,-1.44 0.34,-2.9 0.53,-4.34 0.15,-1.2 0.31,-2.39 0.47,-3.59 0.23,-1.69 0.47,-3.39 0.73,-5.07 0,-0.25 0.07,-0.51 0.11,-0.75 1.825189,-12.29838 4.312131,-24.48941 7.45,-36.52 3.284591,-12.62014 7.478897,-24.98582 12.55,-37 5.389652,-12.56826 11.700148,-24.72131 18.88,-36.36 129.53833,36.73328 9.66275,145.05688 -42.84,145.41 z" />
    <path fill="orange"
      d="m 186.8,658.23 c 1.24,0.26 2.47,0.51 3.69,0.72 1.66,0.32 3.31,0.61 5,0.86 0.32,0.05 0.65,0.1 1,0.13 0.66,0.11 1.34,0.2 2,0.29 1.67,0.23 3.33,0.42 5,0.57 0.79,0.08 1.59,0.15 2.39,0.21 l 1.93,0.15 v 0 c 1.05,0.08 2.09,0.14 3.12,0.17 0.64,0 1.28,0.06 1.94,0.08 h 1.52 1.89 2.57 1.15 c 0.86,0 1.72,0 2.57,-0.08 h 0.06 c 0.59,0 1.19,0 1.79,-0.08 0.16652,0.01 0.33348,0.01 0.5,0 0.5,0 1,0 1.48,-0.07 h 0.35 l 3.35,-0.26 c 1.1,-0.1 2.21,-0.23 3.33,-0.35 l 2.28,-0.27 c 9.27578,-1.29971 18.44848,-3.25121 27.45,-5.84 20.22,-5.64 40,-13.53 60.21,-19.31 26.13,-7.45 55,-11.11 80.25,-2 C 347.62734,488.38675 186.8,482.84379 186.8,658.23 Z M 403.57,58.64 C 379.83738,58.382876 356.16913,61.158678 333.14,66.9 278.25,80.69 229,110.6 186.8,148.8 237.84564,439.31818 403.57,340.22579 403.57,58.64 Z M 682,180.6 c -13.58,-0.48 -27.08,-4.78 -39.29,-11.42 -23.35,-12.7 -42,-32.31 -62.84,-48.86 C 536.57,85.85 482.87,65.05 427.78,59.89 359.64939,243.32902 854.7729,370.03315 682,180.6 Z m 28.19,-5 c 31.00768,35.06164 29.89,38.71166 29.89,-8.6 -10.01,1.24 -18.78,4.19 -29.85,8.56 z m -282.37,471.08 7,5.46 v 0 c 0,0 4.95,4.11 7.42,6.18 l 2.49,2.06 c 1.19,1 2.39,2 3.6,2.94 2.4,1.94667 4.82333,3.86667 7.27,5.76 1.21,1 2.45,1.9 3.68,2.84 19.52711,14.9297 40.12603,28.40272 61.63,40.31 4.82,2.66667 9.68333,5.27 14.59,7.81 3.27,1.67 6.56,3.33 9.86,4.94 4.96,2.42 9.96,4.75333 15,7 v 0 c 46.46636,20.85841 95.60112,35.17143 146,42.53 11.19333,1.65333 22.43,2.95333 33.71,3.9 C 746.72463,555.50461 427.82,372.86841 427.82,646.68 Z M 764.36,166.82 c -4.07753,60.70359 4.75692,40.96048 38.15,4.32 -12.64,-2.04 -25.35667,-3.49667 -38.15,-4.37 z M 1067,698.71 C 1018.3635,366.94214 764.82925,650.19372 764.36,780 c 19.56503,0.82193 39.16014,0.58826 58.7,-0.7 v 0 h 0.34 c 9.33333,-0.58667 18.62333,-1.44 27.87,-2.56 h 0.21 c 49.33062,-5.74122 97.56677,-18.61205 143.2,-38.21 m 132,-318.93 c -1.14,-2.69 -2.33,-5.36 -3.54,-8 -2.26,-5 -4.65,-9.86 -7.11,-14.72 -45.7806,57.32379 -15.3744,137.17216 36.22,138.28 -0.03,-39.16 -9.94,-79.16 -25.54,-115.61 z m -34.35,256.88 c 16.88,-16.18 31.14,-34.69 41.41,-55.85 12.35,-25.48 18,-53.07 18.46,-81.17 -92.7659,-14.2263 -59.87,63.92698 -59.87,137.02 z m 0,-319.92 c -0.1579,28.62312 -7.3011,36 21.48,36 -6.4981,-12.39277 -13.6584,-24.42684 -21.45,-36.05 z m -206,-162.6 c -1.58,-0.6 -3.16,-1.21 -4.75,-1.8 -16.76914,-6.19272 -33.90517,-11.34255 -51.31,-15.42 -138.49552,121.35354 31.21604,66.08 149.03,66.08 -28.93791,-19.91952 -60.13571,-36.33747 -92.94,-48.91 z m 99.06,53.17 c -402.99664,-60.82862 82.76,286.28035 82.76,76.87 -24.0977,-29.14421 -51.9113,-55.00443 -82.73,-76.92 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your paths have different fill colors. The merged path will have one fill color. Is that OK?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Yes, I just added these colors to better understand the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate '**d**' atributtes of the path elements, replace the first **m** with **M**:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1105.04 782.74">
  <g transform="translate(-47.24 -58.63)">
    <path fill="#ff0000"
      d="m 61.08,396.83 c 153.08053,-29.59584 98.70463,188.17778 101.49,254.17 -0.17,-0.05 -0.32,-0.11 -0.48,-0.17 -2.68,-1.06 -5.34,-2.18 -8,-3.38 l -1.7,-0.77 c -2.66667,-1.26 -5.33333,-2.59333 -8,-4 -0.93,-0.49 -1.86,-1 -2.78,-1.52 -14.80417,-8.29279 -28.25298,-18.80094 -39.88,-31.16 -0.34,-0.33 -0.66,-0.68 -1,-1 -1.62,-1.76 -3.21,-3.54 -4.75,-5.36 l -1.7,-2 c -1.82,-2.23 -3.58,-4.52 -5.29,-6.84 -0.25,-0.34 -0.49,-0.68 -0.75,-1 -6.954529,-9.64272 -12.728994,-20.08376 -17.2,-31.1 -0.14,-0.33 -0.26,-0.69 -0.39,-1 -1.373333,-3.53333 -2.59,-7.1 -3.65,-10.7 -0.46,-1.51 -0.9,-3 -1.28,-4.57 -0.14,-0.46 -0.26,-0.91 -0.37,-1.36 C 59.67,522.9 59,499.87 59,477 v -8 c 0,-9.25 0.11,-18.56 0.27,-27.86 0,-2.41 0.1,-4.81 0.15,-7.23 0.14,-6.14 0.34,-12.28 0.6,-18.42 0.06,-1.71 0.14,-3.41 0.23,-5.11 0,-0.98 0.05,-1.96 0.15,-2.94 0.24,-3.56 0.44,-7.09 0.68,-10.61 z M 106.9,242.81 c 9.04946,-14.16423 18.93707,-27.77514 29.61,-40.76 8.27,-10.16 17,-20.06 26.06,-29.6 2.89351,66.44329 8.44745,70.36 -55.67,70.36 z M 61.4,392.55 c 0,-0.42 0.07,-0.85 0.1,-1.27 0.09,-1.15 0.18,-2.3 0.28,-3.44 0.11,-1.34 0.23,-2.69 0.36,-4 0.13,-1.31 0.27,-2.91 0.42,-4.36 0.15,-1.45 0.29,-2.92 0.46,-4.37 0.17,-1.45 0.32,-2.9 0.5,-4.34 0.18,-1.44 0.34,-2.9 0.53,-4.34 0.15,-1.2 0.31,-2.39 0.47,-3.59 0.23,-1.69 0.47,-3.39 0.73,-5.07 0,-0.25 0.07,-0.51 0.11,-0.75 1.825189,-12.29838 4.312131,-24.48941 7.45,-36.52 3.284591,-12.62014 7.478897,-24.98582 12.55,-37 5.389652,-12.56826 11.700148,-24.72131 18.88,-36.36 129.53833,36.73328 9.66275,145.05688 -42.84,145.41 M 186.8,658.23 c 1.24,0.26 2.47,0.51 3.69,0.72 1.66,0.32 3.31,0.61 5,0.86 0.32,0.05 0.65,0.1 1,0.13 0.66,0.11 1.34,0.2 2,0.29 1.67,0.23 3.33,0.42 5,0.57 0.79,0.08 1.59,0.15 2.39,0.21 l 1.93,0.15 v 0 c 1.05,0.08 2.09,0.14 3.12,0.17 0.64,0 1.28,0.06 1.94,0.08 h 1.52 1.89 2.57 1.15 c 0.86,0 1.72,0 2.57,-0.08 h 0.06 c 0.59,0 1.19,0 1.79,-0.08 0.16652,0.01 0.33348,0.01 0.5,0 0.5,0 1,0 1.48,-0.07 h 0.35 l 3.35,-0.26 c 1.1,-0.1 2.21,-0.23 3.33,-0.35 l 2.28,-0.27 c 9.27578,-1.29971 18.44848,-3.25121 27.45,-5.84 20.22,-5.64 40,-13.53 60.21,-19.31 26.13,-7.45 55,-11.11 80.25,-2 C 347.62734,488.38675 186.8,482.84379 186.8,658.23 Z M 403.57,58.64 C 379.83738,58.382876 356.16913,61.158678 333.14,66.9 278.25,80.69 229,110.6 186.8,148.8 237.84564,439.31818 403.57,340.22579 403.57,58.64 Z M 682,180.6 c -13.58,-0.48 -27.08,-4.78 -39.29,-11.42 -23.35,-12.7 -42,-32.31 -62.84,-48.86 C 536.57,85.85 482.87,65.05 427.78,59.89 359.64939,243.32902 854.7729,370.03315 682,180.6 Z m 28.19,-5 c 31.00768,35.06164 29.89,38.71166 29.89,-8.6 -10.01,1.24 -18.78,4.19 -29.85,8.56 z m -282.37,471.08 7,5.46 v 0 c 0,0 4.95,4.11 7.42,6.18 l 2.49,2.06 c 1.19,1 2.39,2 3.6,2.94 2.4,1.94667 4.82333,3.86667 7.27,5.76 1.21,1 2.45,1.9 3.68,2.84 19.52711,14.9297 40.12603,28.40272 61.63,40.31 4.82,2.66667 9.68333,5.27 14.59,7.81 3.27,1.67 6.56,3.33 9.86,4.94 4.96,2.42 9.96,4.75333 15,7 v 0 c 46.46636,20.85841 95.60112,35.17143 146,42.53 11.19333,1.65333 22.43,2.95333 33.71,3.9 C 746.72463,555.50461 427.82,372.86841 427.82,646.68 Z M 764.36,166.82 c -4.07753,60.70359 4.75692,40.96048 38.15,4.32 -12.64,-2.04 -25.35667,-3.49667 -38.15,-4.37 z M 1067,698.71 C 1018.3635,366.94214 764.82925,650.19372 764.36,780 c 19.56503,0.82193 39.16014,0.58826 58.7,-0.7 v 0 h 0.34 c 9.33333,-0.58667 18.62333,-1.44 27.87,-2.56 h 0.21 c 49.33062,-5.74122 97.56677,-18.61205 143.2,-38.21 m 132,-318.93 c -1.14,-2.69 -2.33,-5.36 -3.54,-8 -2.26,-5 -4.65,-9.86 -7.11,-14.72 -45.7806,57.32379 -15.3744,137.17216 36.22,138.28 -0.03,-39.16 -9.94,-79.16 -25.54,-115.61 z m -34.35,256.88 c 16.88,-16.18 31.14,-34.69 41.41,-55.85 12.35,-25.48 18,-53.07 18.46,-81.17 -92.7659,-14.2263 -59.87,63.92698 -59.87,137.02 z m 0,-319.92 c -0.1579,28.62312 -7.3011,36 21.48,36 -6.4981,-12.39277 -13.6584,-24.42684 -21.45,-36.05 z m -206,-162.6 c -1.58,-0.6 -3.16,-1.21 -4.75,-1.8 -16.76914,-6.19272 -33.90517,-11.34255 -51.31,-15.42 -138.49552,121.35354 31.21604,66.08 149.03,66.08 -28.93791,-19.91952 -60.13571,-36.33747 -92.94,-48.91 z m 99.06,53.17 c -402.99664,-60.82862 82.76,286.28035 82.76,76.87 -24.0977,-29.14421 -51.9113,-55.00443 -82.73,-76.92 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question but actually, I need to close all the little openings around this pattern and fill the whole image with red.

Comment: I suppose it cannot be done by text editing... You can select manually all the external contour points in Inkscape and create a new path from them and then remove the old path, but it's a lot of work